# Angular 9 anchor tag (click) not firing

Tags: html, angular

I have read most of the posts regarding this issue and have tried all of the things I have come across, but basically I have some code:

```
<div class="chi-dropdown__menu -list -w&#45;&#45;lg" style="position: absolute; top: 49px" [ngClass]="{'-active':isChannelMenuActive}" >
  <a class="chi-dropdown__menu-item -h&#45;&#45;auto -active" (click)="goToMediaPortal()">
     <span class="chi-dropdown__menu-item_title" >Media Portal</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

The problem is that href="#" does not work, nor does using [routerLink]="". In fact, taking the click event out of the equation and just adding href="url.here" doesn't work either.  The event is not firing, it's not getting hit at all.  Any suggestions?

***EDIT***

When I take the

```
[ngClass]="{'-active':isChannelMenuActive}"
```

off of the dropdown menu and just set that to -active to make sure it shows, the event fires fine.  Any idea why adding Angular directives would hijack the anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

Use [href]="url.here" or href="{{url.here}}

Comment: This didn't work either.  Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding role="button" to the anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.   However, it didn't work for me either.